# Display Errors on validation

Tags: php, mysqli, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use am using bootstrap.. I need to display errors 1 at a time. the following code post the errors in different rows and it consumes a whole page.

if there is an issue in the first field only post that error before continuing to the next field instead of posting all fields at once.

```
function validate_registration(){
    $errors = [];    

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {


        $email = clean($_POST['email']);        
        $user_name = clean($_POST['user_name']);
        $birthdate = clean($_POST['birthdate']);
        $country = clean($_POST['country']);
        $password = clean($_POST['password']);
        $confirm_password = clean($_POST['confirm_password']);


        if (empty($email)) {
            $errors[] = "Email Address Required.";
        }
        if (email_exists($email)) {
            $errors[] = "Email Address in use.";
        }

        if (empty($user_name)) {
            $errors[] = "Username Required.";
        }
        if (strlen($user_name) < $min) {
            $errors[] = "Username is to short.";
        }

        if (user_exists($user_name)) {
            $errors[] = "Username Taken.";
        }

        if (empty($birthdate)) {
            $errors[] = "Birthdate Required.";
        }

        if (empty($country)) {
            $errors[] = "Country Required.";
        }

        if (empty($password)) {
            $errors[] = "Password Required.";
        }

        if ($password !== $confirm_password) {            
            $errors[] = "Your password fields do not match";
        }

        if (! empty($errors)) {            
            foreach ($errors as $error) {                
                echo validation_errors($error);
            }
        } else {

            if (register_user($email, $user_name, $birthdate, $country, $password)) {

             set_message('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
             Please check your email for account Information.</div>');

             redirect("../account/login.php");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just replace $errors[] with $errors.

Comment: @RaviHirani wouldn't this cause last error to be overwritten over previous?

Comment: @devpro there is not error if you try to register say everything is blank it post all errors and you have to click each one to close I want to post each error per field

Comment: @SagarGuhe: He needs one error at a time. I know this a bad way. But he will get what he needs.

Comment: instead of posting all errors just post each row

Comment: @RaviHirani that did nothing it removed all validation

Comment: @Rome: you also need to remove your foreach loop because  $errors is a string now instead of an array.

Comment: @Rome: If I am not wrong then you want to put focus on your very first error. Am I correct?

Comment: @RaviHirani if you go here http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts you can see bootstrap alerts now lets say you click register with empty fields it will post 5 different errors field required which pushes down the login page if user has error in email I would like it to post that error only then when they move to the next field if there is a error it will only post that field

Comment: u r looking for client side validation

Comment: if u submit the form, and u need to print only ist error, not all, ??? server side or client side? @Rome

Comment: @Rome:- Visit the link that I have attached in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do the same by keeping your existing code.

Just replace this code:-

```
     if (!empty($errors)) {              
        echo validation_errors($errors[0]);               
     }
```

You can also get the same functionality by `if else if` way. declare $error as a string.

```
$error = ''; 

if(empty($email)) {
            $error = "Email Address Required.";
        }
        else if (email_exists($email)) {
            $error = "Email Address in use.";
        }

        else if (empty($user_name)) {
            $error = "Username Required.";
        }
        else if (strlen($user_name) < $min) {
            $error = "Username is to short.";
        }

        else if (user_exists($user_name)) {
            $error = "Username Taken.";
        }

        else if (empty($birthdate)) {
            $error = "Birthdate Required.";
        }

        else if (empty($country)) {
            $error = "Country Required.";
        }

        else if (empty($password)) {
            $error = "Password Required.";
        }

        else if ($password !== $confirm_password) {            
            $error = "Your password fields do not match";
        }

       if (!empty($error)) { 

                echo validation_errors($error);

        } else {

            if (register_user($email, $user_name, $birthdate, $country, $password)) {

             set_message('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
             Please check your email for account Information.</div>');

             redirect("../account/login.php");

            }
        }
```

For Bootstrap Validations, Just visit this [link](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/):-

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: @devpro:- If I am not wrong then he needs client side validation for his form. I have posted solution for server side validation to get very first error. I have also updated my answer and post a link for him which gives you exact bootstrap validations.

Comment: Ravi Hirani thank you so much that is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: for very ist error, why not if elseif?? with current code?

Comment: @devpro: Yes. I am agree with you. If else is better than array way. I gave him minimal solution with his current code. I am also editing my answer with your suggested way.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

As per your comments, if you want to print one error at a time than you need to use ELSEIF instead of IF like:

```
if (empty($email)) {
    $errors[] = "Email Address Required.";
}
elseif (email_exists($email)) {
    $errors[] = "Email Address in use.";
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are not using jquery validation for client side validation

and then use server side validation too but display it as all 
    error in loop instead of inline .

Because client as well as server side validation is useful